# LogIn with spring security not work

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, thymeleaf

i'm tring to do a login with spring security,but it not work, because it return to me this link: http://localhost:8080/login?error
and report me on the main page:
this is the code:

An index in the static page, it relink me:

```
<a href="login">LogIn</a>
```

in the template i have this:

```
<h2>Digita il tuo username e la tua password per accedere al sistema </h2>
                <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" th:object="${responsabile}">
                    <div class="field half first">
                        <label for="name"><span class="icon fa-user"></span>Username:</label>
                        <input name="name" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" th:field="*{nomeUtente}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field half">
                        <label for="email"><span class="icon fa-code"></span> Password:</label>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="password" placeholder="Password" th:field="*{chiaveAccesso}"/>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><input value="Login" class="button" type="submit"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
```

and the request mapping that catch it is there:

```
        package it.uniroma3.controller;

    import it.uniroma3.model.Centro;
    import it.uniroma3.model.Responsabile;
    import it.uniroma3.service.CentroService;
    import it.uniroma3.service.ResponsabileService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import javax.validation.Valid;

    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @Autowired
        private ResponsabileService responsabileService;
        @Autowired
        private CentroService centroService;

        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public String login(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("responsabile", new Responsabile());
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/role")
        public String loginRole(HttpSession session, Model model) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String role = auth.getAuthorities().toString();
            Responsabile responsabile = this.responsabileService.findByNomeUtente(auth.getName());

            String targetUrl = "";
            if(role.contains("RESPONSABILE")) {
                session.setAttribute("responsabile", responsabile);
                Centro centro=this.centroService.findById(responsabile.getCentro().getId());
                session.setAttribute("centro", centro);
                model.addAttribute("username",responsabile.getNomeUtente());
                targetUrl = "/responsabile/respPanel";
            } else if(role.contains("DIRETTORE")) {
                session.setAttribute("responsabile", responsabile);
                model.addAttribute("username", responsabile.getNomeUtente());
                targetUrl = "/direttore/direttorePanel";
            }

            return targetUrl;
        }





    }
```

i use like support that class:

```
@Entity
```

public class Responsabile {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String nome;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String cognome;

@Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
private String nomeUtente;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String chiaveAccesso;

@ManyToOne  //ok
private Azienda azienda;

@OneToOne   //ok
private Azienda aziendadiretta;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Centro centro;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String role;
```

and

```
        package it.uniroma3.error;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;

    // handle 403 page
    @Component
    public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAccessDeniedHandler.class);

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                        AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

            Authentication auth
                    = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if (auth != null) {
                logger.info("User '" + auth.getName()
                        + "' attempted to access the protected URL: "
                        + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
            }

            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest.getContextPath() + "/403");

        }
    }
```

Secutiry Config CLass:

```
            package it.uniroma3.security;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
        import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

        import javax.sql.DataSource;

        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
        public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            private final String usersQuery = "SELECT nome_utente,chiave_accesso,TRUE FROM responsabile WHERE nome_utente = ?";
            private final String rolesQuery = "SELECT nome_utente,role FROM responsabile WHERE nome_utente = ?";

            @Qualifier("dataSource")
            @Autowired
            private DataSource dataSource;

            @Autowired
            private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

            @Bean
            public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
                return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                        .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery);
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("DIRETTORE")
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("RESPONSABILE")
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/role")
                        .and()
                        .logout()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
            }


            @Autowired
            public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder())
                        .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery);
            }

            //Spring Boot configured this already.
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
                web
                        .ignoring()
                        .antMatchers("/static/**","/assets/**","/images/**" );
            }

            /*
            @Autowired
            public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth
                        .inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser("superadmin").password("superadmin").roles("SUPERADMIN");
            }
            */

        }
```

Logs:
Started ProgettoSiwApplication in 6.958 seconds (JVM running for 7.964)
2018-06-21 12:55:36.453  INFO 13584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-06-21 12:55:36.453  INFO 13584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-06-21 12:55:36.487  INFO 13584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 34 ms

Comment: Where is your spring security config class ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski i add it now thanks

Comment: Please if there isn't something ask to me i need that done

Comment: Put breakpoint inside loginRole method in your LoginController and check if the program stop there

Comment: Is there any exception thrown in spring logs ?

Comment: i don't see exception, it work, i have no log of error, 
i have put a breakpoint there:
        return targetUrl;
but it's like i don't go there

Comment: @RafałSokalski please use a response so i can't copy same text or you don't know how appen

Comment: put a  breakpoint on first line at this method

Comment: @RafałSokalski i have put this on the line and start up the application, i use it but nothing appen, i'm using it right?

Comment: Of course you start it in debug mode right ?

Comment: now yes, but i don't know how to read the debug mode, on the method it will not stop in the main yes

Comment: @RafałSokalski on the return of "login" i see i have the responsabile

Comment: it means that the program doesn't even go inside this method, so the problem is much earlier

Comment: @RafałSokalski it's ike he don't enter on the "/role" mapping method, i came back from "loginpage" and login mapping and after it exit

Comment: You should change your .defaultSuccessUrl("/role") in spring security to loginProcessingUrl("/role")

Comment: Because now, you didn't even process login

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: i have change it with "/role"
and now i have this:
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: Bad credentials

i have done something

Comment: Do you have created user ?

Comment: @CristianMonti My modified answer is working fine. First check whether the in-memory authentication is working fine. If so, the issue lies with the jdbc authentication

Answer (score 3):

Please change security configure class as this.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/role")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username("user")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<!--<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>-->
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Find working code here https://gitlab.com/supun/spring-boot-app/commit/be2f0f723f5aec728bcaf777325fb1899d878f8f

Comment: if i use "/role" like loginprocessingurl?

Comment: if i use "/perform_login" i lost my index page